# Why is my retain method being called when a property accessor is being used

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My object is not getting released from memory so I override retain method and put a breakpoint in to see where in code it gets retained.

Every time the object is referenced using a property accessor the retain method is called.  Why would this be happening?

color = self.myobject.color

calls retain.

Comment: Are you doing any lazy initialization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The synthesized property accessor for retained properties looks something like this:

```
- (UIColor *)color
{
    return [[_color retain] autorelease];
}
```

Therefore, your `retain` method is called, but it's balanced with an `autorelease`.

See [this code snippet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW28) in the Objective-C Programming Language Guide for an example of how a synthesized accessor might look (the locking part doesn't apply in the nonatomic case, but the retain-autorelease is the same).

Comment: That’s not how synthesized `retain` accessors work. See Rudy’s answer for the correct version.

Comment: Rudy's answer doesn't even refer to the getter.

Comment: The question here is not why `self.color = myColor` retains `myColor`, but rather why `color = self.myColor` (where the property is only accessed but not changed) also sends a `retain` message.

Comment: Ahh… I’m sorry, I misread. It won’t let me remove the downvote unless your answer is edited, though.

Comment: +1. You are right. So his leak is not really a leak, since he only logs retain, and not release.

Comment: @Noah Witherspoon: FYI, the answer is edited now so you can remove the downvote.

Comment: @Mel: I constantly learn something here. I read many answers to questions, even those I would normally not be interested in. I learned a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Because you probably declared your property as `retain` or `copy`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject* myobject;
```

If you *@synthesize* that, the compiler will generate code that looks more or less like:

```
- (void) setMyobject: (MyObject *) value
{
    if (value != myobject)
    {
        [myobject release];
        myobject = value;
    }
}
```

Each time you assign to `self.myobject`, that method is invoked with the new object as `value` parameter. It should release the old object, but the last object added is retained. You'll have to release it in your dealloc. And you should release what you allocated, so the pattern is:

```
MyObject *myObj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
self.myobject = myObj;
[myObj release];
```

Items returned from a method are usually autoreleased, so you should not release those:

```
MyObject *myObj = [someOtherObject someMethod: 17];
self.myobject = myObj;
// Do NOT release myObj!
```

---

### Update

See **@omz**'s explanation. I misread and was talking about the *setter*. Your *getter* does a *retain* too, but that is immediately paired with an *autorelease*. Since you only log the *retains*, it only *looks* as if you have leaks.

Comment: The question is about the object being retained by the _getter_.

Comment: @omz, that's true. Hmmm... not sure what causes that, unless the getter is not synthesized and the manual implementation does a retain for some reason. Hard to tell.